# Python PIL thumbnail with Image.ANTIALIAS. How to preserve quality

Tags: python, image, python-imaging-library

I'm trying to resize images while keeping aspect ratio. I use PIL's thumbnail method for this. I use Image.ANTIALIAS filter.

You can check my code here:

```
image = Image.open(design.design.path)
format = image.format
image = ImageOps.mirror(image)
new_size = (241, 241)
image.thumbnail(new_size, Image.ANTIALIAS)
image.save(response, format)
```

This code works perfectly however quality is lost after thumbnail. I can see it by zooming in on the saved image. I can see pixels at the corners of the image while I don't on the original image. This is seen even better when I print out resized image.

You can check out sample images here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/CqF6D.jpg

Please tell me if you need anything else

Comment: are you making the images smaller or bigger? either way i'd recommend using the `resize` method rather than the `thumbnail` method

Comment: @JamesKent I'm making them smaller. I'm using thumbnail instead of resize to maintain aspect ratio. Resize does not preserve aspect ratio.

Comment: Why would `resize` not preserve aspect ratio? You hardcode the aspect ratio here to 1:1, and that would also be the aspect ratio if you would use `resize`.

Comment: @physicalattraction yes in this case but this is a demo code and in real application there's a few different sizes I want to resize to which are not squares.

Comment: Still, in that case `resize` keeps the aspect ratio you give it, which can be deduced before you resize it.

Comment: The `thumbnail` method recalculates the given size to preserve the aspect ratio, and then calls `resize`.

Comment: I tried using resize instead of thumbnail but still the same thing happens.

Answer (score 3):

Image.save has options for you:

```
img.save(fpath, 'image/png', quality=100, optimize=True)
```

Comment: I've tried both quality and optimize options but they didn't help.

Comment: Well, i guess this is about resizing and loosing quality rather than compression problem

Answer (score 2):

If you are making thumbnails of a pixel-based image, of course you will loose quality. Re-sizing this kind of image (as opposed to vector images) simply throw information  away - there is no way to recover it.

IF you need to view the image in full size, you have to preserve the original image, and keep the scaled-down version to be shown only where it is needed - use the original for everything else.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raster_graphics